# Combine certain number of rows

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a large list of names in Excel and want to combine them by eights. 
Example:

```
 1. Mark
 2. Cindy
 3. Deb
 4. Mary
 5. Bill
 6. Roxy
 7. Bobby
 8. Richard
```

What I want it to look like:

```
  1. Mark Cindy Deb Mary Bill Roxy Bobby Richard
```

Please keep in mind I am doing this on a large spreadsheet, so I want eight in every cell.

Comment: http://www.xlorate.com/vba-examples.html#Concatenate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You have all data in Column "A" and want to combine them in Column "B", here You have simple macro code that will group it by 8 till not find empty cell.

```
Sub Macro1 ()    
i = 1
    Do Until Cells(i, 1) = ""
    Cells(i, 2) = Cells(i * 8 - 7, 1) & " " & Cells(i * 8 - 6, 1) & " " & Cells(i * 8 - 5, 1) & " " & Cells(i * 8 - 4, 1) & " " & _
        Cells(i * 8 - 3, 1) & " " & Cells(i * 8 - 2, 1) & " " & Cells(i * 8 - 1, 1) & " " & Cells(i * 8 - 0, 1)

    i = i + 1
    Loop
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Mark` is in A2, please try in Row2, copied down to suit:

```
=IF(INT((ROW()-2)/8)<>INT((ROW()-3)/8),OFFSET(A2,0,)&" "&OFFSET(A2,1,)&" "&OFFSET(A2,2,)&" "&OFFSET(A2,3,)&" "&OFFSET(A2,4,)&" "&OFFSET(A2,5,)&" "&OFFSET(A2,6,)&" "&OFFSET(A2,7,),"")
```

If that suits you may then want to select the results, Copy, Paste Special..., Values over the top and then tidy up.

Answer (score 0):

As you included VBA I propose this code:

It has the advantage that it can be set a Shortcut activated macro, and the users can provide the starting cell of the list at the time of initiating the macro. There is also the option to hard code the starting cell within the code *(see comments in the code)*.

```
Sub List_Combine_By()
Const kBy As Byte = 8
Dim CllSource As Range
Dim sNames As String
Dim lIn As Long, lOut As Long
Dim b As Byte

    Rem USE THIS LINE IF ACTIVATED BY A SHORTCUT
    Rem Users provide Starting Cell
    Set CllSource = Selection.Cells(1)

    Rem OTHERWISE USE THIS LINE TO DEFINE THE STARTING CELL
    'Set CllSource = Range("B3")

    With CllSource
        lOut = 0
        For lIn = 1 To .Worksheet.Rows.Count Step 8

            Rem Validate for Completness
            If .Cells(lIn, 1).Value2 = Empty Then Exit For

            Rem Clear Prior Results
            .Offset(lOut, 2).Resize(8, 1).ClearContents

            Rem Concatenate Names By
            sNames = Empty
            For b = 1 To kBy
                sNames = sNames & " " & .Cells(-1 + lIn + b, 1).Value2
            Next

            Rem Write Results
            .Offset(lOut, 2).Value = sNames
            lOut = 1 + lOut

    Next: End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the names start in A1, try this starting in B1 and copied down:-

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROWS(A1:A$1)*8-7)&" "&INDEX(A:A,ROWS(A1:A$1)*8-6)&" "&INDEX(A:A,ROWS(A1:A$1)*8-5)&" "&INDEX(A:A,ROWS(A1:A$1)*8-4)&" "&INDEX(A:A,ROWS(A1:A$1)*8-3)&" "&INDEX(A:A,ROWS(A1:A$1)*8-2)&" "&INDEX(A:A,ROWS(A1:A$1)*8-1)&" "&INDEX(A:A,ROWS(A1:A$1)*8)
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried array formulas? Sounds perfect for your situation. Combine it with CONCATENATE and it would be easy to reach the solution.

Some samples here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7

Comment: sorry, I've made a mistake. Maybe it's possible using some macros because concatenate function isn't able to concatenate matrix. If you don't want to write you own macro, you can use and add-in which adds MCONCAT function to Excel. 

Yoy can check it here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/365691-concatenate-multiple-cells-array-formula.html